# Python curve_fit creating odd corners

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, curve-fitting, chemistry

I'm trying to fit some data to a nernst curve, but the fitted line has odd angles that don't fit either the data or the equation.  Do you know why this is?

```py
csv_file='031109twohemesplit.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
Eh=data['Eh']
Fracred=data['frac red']
tmp_Fracred=Fracred-Fracred.min()
normFracred = tmp_Fracred / tmp_Fracred.max()
plt.scatter(Eh,normFracred)
def twopot(Eh, Em1, Em2, z):
    return 0.5/(10**((Eh-Em1)/(8.14*275.15/(1*96.485)))+z)+0.5/(10**((Eh-Em2)/(8.14*275.15/(1*96.485)))+z)
guess=[-250,-325, 1]
popt, pcov=curve_fit(twopot,Eh,normFracred,guess,method='dogbox')
print(popt)
plt.plot(Eh,twopot(Eh,*popt), label='fitted')
```

It yields this:

[image]

Comment: What is `curve_fit`?

Answer (score 2):

The "odd corners" happen, because of this command:

```
plt.plot(Eh,twopot(Eh,*popt), label='fitted')
```

You're feeding the `twopot` function only values from your data points in `Eh`. So in between two points, your curve will just be a straight line which results in "odd corners".

To plot your fitted curve, instead of the values of `Eh`, use generated values from an appropriate `np.linspace` over the same range as `Eh`:

```
x = np.linspace(min(Eh), max(Eh), 200)
plt.plot(x, twopot(x,*popt), label='fitted')
```

The level of "detail" of your curve is determined by how many points you select to generate with the `np.linspace` command. In the example above, it's 200 values.